# How to make game a draw with existing code

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, dom

I've created functions with all winning combinations for player one and player two but need to create one for a draw and don't want to write out all possible draw combinations. What would be the best way to attempt this?
I was thinking if I could make the playerOneWin and playerTwoWin function true if they run I could have a draw function() that says if both are false then the match is a draw, or if all boxes are fille and playerOne and playerTwo haven't won then it is a draw.

```js
var box1 = document.querySelector(".box1");
var box2 = document.querySelector(".box2");
var box3 = document.querySelector(".box3");
var box4 = document.querySelector(".box4");
var box5 = document.querySelector(".box5");
var box6 = document.querySelector(".box6");
var box7 = document.querySelector(".box7");
var box8 = document.querySelector(".box8");
var box9 = document.querySelector(".box9");

var activePlayer;

var playerOne = "X";
var playerTwo = "O";

activePlayer = playerOne;

function clickBoxPlayer(event) {
  if (activePlayer === playerOne) {
    var boxClicked = event.target;

    if (
      boxClicked.innerHTML === playerOne ||
      boxClicked.innerHTML === playerTwo
    ) {
      console.log("noturturn");
    } else if (boxClicked.innerHTML === "") {
      boxClicked.innerHTML = activePlayer;
      activePlayer = playerTwo;
    }
    console.log("one");
    //tie && winning function

    function playerOneWin() {
      if (
        box1.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box2.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box3.innerHTML === playerOne
      ) {
        console.log("playeronewins");
      } else if (
        box1.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box4.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box7.innerHTML === playerOne
      ) {
        console.log("playeronewins");
      } else if (
        box1.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box5.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box9.innerHTML === playerOne
      ) {
        console.log("playeronewins");
      } else if (
        box2.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box5.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box8.innerHTML === playerOne
      ) {
        console.log("playeronewins");
      } else if (
        box3.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box6.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box9.innerHTML === playerOne
      ) {
        console.log("playeronewins");
      } else if (
        box3.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box5.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box7.innerHTML === playerOne
      ) {
        console.log("playeronewins");
      } else if (
        box4.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box5.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box6.innerHTML === playerOne
      ) {
        console.log("playeronewins");
      } else if (
        box7.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box8.innerHTML === playerOne &&
        box9.innerHTML === playerOne
      ) {
        console.log("playeronewins");
      }
    }
    playerOneWin();
  } else if (activePlayer === playerTwo) {
    var boxClicked = event.target;

    if (
      boxClicked.innerHTML === playerOne ||
      boxClicked.innerHTML === playerTwo
    ) {
      console.log("noturturn");
    } else if (boxClicked.innerHTML === "") {
      boxClicked.innerHTML = activePlayer;
      activePlayer = playerOne;
    }

    console.log("two");
  }
  //player two winning combinations
  function playerTwoWin() {
    if (
      box1.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box2.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box3.innerHTML === playerTwo
    ) {
      console.log("playertwowins");
    } else if (
      box1.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box4.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box7.innerHTML === playerTwo
    ) {
      console.log("playertwowins");
    } else if (
      box1.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box5.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box9.innerHTML === playerTwo
    ) {
      console.log("playertwowins");
    } else if (
      box2.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box5.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box8.innerHTML === playerTwo
    ) {
      console.log("playertwowins");
    } else if (
      box3.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box6.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box9.innerHTML === playerTwo
    ) {
      console.log("playertwowins");
    } else if (
      box3.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box5.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box7.innerHTML === playerTwo
    ) {
      console.log("playertwowins");
    } else if (
      box4.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box5.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box6.innerHTML === playerTwo
    ) {
      console.log("playertwowins");
    } else if (
      box7.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box8.innerHTML === playerTwo &&
      box9.innerHTML === playerTwo
    ) {
      console.log("playertwowins");
    }
  }
  playerTwoWin();
}

var allBoxes = document.querySelector(".allBoxes");
allBoxes.addEventListener("click", clickBoxPlayer);
```

```css
.allBoxes div {
  display     : block;
  float       : left;
  width       : 2em;
  height      : 2em;
  margin      : .3em;
  background  : lightgrey;
  text-align  : center;
  line-height : 1.8em;
  cursor      : pointer;
  }
.allBoxes div:nth-of-type(4),
.allBoxes div:nth-of-type(7) {
  clear : left;
  }
```

```html
<section class="allBoxes">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
  <div class="box5"></div>
  <div class="box6"></div>
  <div class="box7"></div>
  <div class="box8"></div>
  <div class="box9"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, if you changed your `playerOneWin` and `playerTwoWin` functions to return `true` or `false` based on the checks that you are already doing and if you also add a function that returns `true` if all boxes are filled (and `false` otherwise), then you can use them to check for the winning and the draw conditions like this

```
    if (playerOneWin()) {
        console.log("playeronewins");
    }

    // your other code

    if (playerTwoWin()) {
        console.log("playertwowins");
    }
    else if (allBoxesFilled() && !playerOneWin()) {
        console.log("draw");
    }
```

EDIT: to check all of the boxes you can put all of them (box1 - box9) into an array

```
// you could also do this by selecting all boxes
// with a document.querySelectorAll(...)
const boxes = [box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6, box7, box8, box9]
```

and then call `.every` on the `boxes` array with a predicate function. The predicate function has to return `true`, when the condition you are interested in is met, and `false` when the condition is not met. The condition you are interested in is that each box has to be filled, so it must not be empty, so the condition is `innerHTML !== ""`. With such predicate function `.every` will return `true` only if the condition is `true` for all the items in the array (every means every item meets the condition in the predicate function). Which gives us the following code

```
const allBoxesFilled = boxes.every(box => box.innerHTML !== "")
```

You can use it like this in your code (instead of the function call), or put it into a function

```
function allBoxesFilled() {
  const boxes = [box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6, box7, box8, box9]
  return boxes.every(box => box.innerHTML !== "")
}
```

Comment: what can I use to check if there is innerhtml inside of each box for allBoxesFilled?

Comment: @goatstash: See my edit. I added an example with explanation how you could go about constructing such a function.

Answer (score 0):

the way to do that:

```js
const
  Boxes    = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#allBoxes > div'))
, players  = ['x','o']
, winCases = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8]] 
  ;
var 
  playerNum = 0
, winnerIs  = ''
  ;
document.querySelector('#allBoxes').onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('#allBoxes div')
    || winnerIs != '' 
    ) return

  if (target.textContent ==='')
    {
    target.textContent = players[playerNum]
    checkWinner(players[playerNum])
    playerNum = ++playerNum % 2
  } }
function checkWinner(player)
  {
  if (winCases.some(suite=>suite.every(x=>Boxes[x].textContent === player )))
    {
    winnerIs = player
    console.log(' winner is:',player)
     
    for (let [a,b,c] of winCases)
      {
      if ( Boxes[a].textContent === player
        && Boxes[b].textContent === player
        && Boxes[c].textContent === player
        ){
        Boxes[a].className = Boxes[b].className = Boxes[c].className = 'win'
        break;
  } } } }
```

```css
#allBoxes div {
  display     : block;
  float       : left;
  width       : 2em;
  height      : 2em;
  margin      : .3em;
  background  : lightgrey;
  text-align  : center;
  line-height : 1.8em;
  cursor      : pointer;
  }
#allBoxes div:nth-of-type(4),
#allBoxes div:nth-of-type(7) {
  clear : left;
  }
#allBoxes div.win {
  background : yellow;
  }
```

```html
<section id="allBoxes">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
</section>
```